# Missing u-strings on Python 3.2?

Tags: python, unicode, travis-ci, nose, six

I have a litany of unit tests that are run on Travis CI and *only* on PY3.2 it goes belly up. How can I solve this without using six.u()?

```
def test_parse_utf8(self):
    s = String("foo", 12, encoding="utf8")
    self.assertEqual(s.parse(b"hello joh\xd4\x83n"), u"hello joh\u0503n")

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: SyntaxError (invalid syntax (test_strings.py, line 37))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.2.5/lib/python3.2/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.2.5/lib/python3.2/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.2.5/lib/python3.2/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.2.5/lib/python3.2/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/travis/build/construct/construct/tests/test_strings.py", line 37
    self.assertEqual(s.build(u"hello joh\u0503n"), b"hello joh\xd4\x83n")
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Trying to get this to work:

```
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3
def u(s): return s if PY3 else s.decode("utf-8")

self.assertEqual(s.parse(b"hello joh\xd4\x83n"), u("hello joh\u0503n"))
```

---

Quote from https://pythonhosted.org/six/

> On Python 2, u() doesn’t know what the encoding of the literal is.
>   Each byte is converted directly to the unicode codepoint of the same
>   value. Because of this, it’s only safe to use u() with strings of
>   ASCII data.

But the whole point of using unicode is to not be restricted to ASCII.

Comment: Yeah, 3.2 just doesn't have that syntax. Are you required to support Python 2 and Python 3.2 with the same codebase, without using `2to3`?

Comment: @ArekBulski: 2to3 should never tell you to use `six`. I don't think any code anywhere in 2to3 knows about `six`. When I run 2to3 on code with `u` literals, it just strips the `u`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're out of luck here.

Either use `six.u()` or drop support for Python 3.2.

Comment: The source is here: https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/b5b578da87f8ed18bb2b8c077f2d24cc5d912c7c/luigi/six.py#L646-L647

Essentially, it let's Python 3 strings pass through and converts to unicode on Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Could you instead do `from __future__ import unicode_literals` and not use the `u` syntax anywhere?

`from __future__ import unicode_literals` makes string literals without a preceding `u` in earlier versions of Python act as in Python 3, that is default to unicode. So if you do `from __future__ import unicode_literals` and change all `u"strings"` to `"strings"`, your string literals will be unicode in all versions. This will not affect `b` literals.

Comment: This solution fails on Travis.

Answer (score 0):

I taken the implementation of `six.u()` and discarded `six`.

```
import sys
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3
def u(s): return s if PY3 else unicode(s.replace(r'\\', r'\\\\'), "unicode_escape")
```